# PHP 5 code not working in PHP 4

Tags: php

I have this function in PHP 5:

```
function myPHPFunction($shows) {

        foreach($shows as &$show) {
                        $showData = $this->Api->getID(null, $show->showId, false);
                        $show->Id = $showData->Id;
        }
        return $shows;
}
```

the $shows array has empty id, I am able to get the id with an Api call and when I return $shows at the end, the id field is populated. If I move this code to PHP 4:

```
function myPHPFunction($shows) {

        foreach($shows as $show) {
                        $showData = $this->Api->getID(null, $show->showId, false);
                        $show->Id = $showData->Id;
        }
        return $shows;
}
```

The $shows array still has an empty id field when I return is. Does it have something to with &$ because the & does not work in PHP 4

Comment: `foreach($shows as $key => $show) { $shows[$key]->Id = $showData->Id; }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes *pass by reference* was available only after PHP 4.0.4

> There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning
>   saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use &
>   in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was
>   removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

[`Source`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)